# Is Context Broker Federation possible with NGSI LD?

Tags: fiware-orion

NGSI LD does not seem to define or implement `"/op/notify"`, which was the endpoint of `"Context Broker Federation"` implemented in `NGSIv2`.
Is there an equivalent function in NGSI LD?

■ [manual](https://github.com/FIWARE/context.Orion-LD/blob/develop/doc/manuals/user/federation.md)

■ [Spec](https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_gs/CIM/001_099/009/01.04.02_60/gs_cim009v010402p.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Orion-LD does not implement federation yet. The concept is being defined in ETSI ISG CIM and until it is decided exactly how it is to work (in a standard way), it cannot be implemented (unless we're willing to reimplement it once it gets defined in ETSI).

That said, Scorpio (another NGSi-LD broker) implements its own "NEC proprietary" federation scheme.

About "/op/notify", it is actually implemented in Orion-LD (POST /ngsi-ld/ex/v1/notify), it's just not meant for federation but for maintaining a local copy of some other broker's entities, based on subscriptions/notifications. This feature in brand new and was added to Orion-LD a few weeks ago.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I tried "/ngsi-ld/ex/v1/notify" because what we want to achieve is mutual entity copying between brokers based on notifications.
When I created subscriptions with "/ngsi-ld/ex/v1/notify" as the endpoint in multiple Orions (A and B) and created an entity in A, the notifications cycled a certain number of times.（"timesSent": 2196）
With "/op/notify" in V2, the notifications were mutual only once, is there any way to get the same result with "/ngsi-ld/ex/v1/notify"?
Or are there plans to fix this in future implementations?

Comment: Also, I couldn't find "/ngsi-ld/ex/v1/notify" in the latest published specs, will it be added in the future?
https://www.etsi.org/deliver/etsi_gs/CIM/001_099/009/01.04.02_60/gs_cim009v010402p.pdf